# Button click changes to other CSS file and back {JavaScript, jQuery}

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a question for your guys.
I made a website with mainly a grille that has some properties like colors, heights, widths...
[Looks of website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GjwP.png)
These styles are made in 'bord.css'. Now, I have a script that, by clicking the button 'Change style', will change the  destination to another CSS file named 'bord2.css'. THIS WORKS! By using an if-else-statement it'll try to check whether it is the 'bord.css' or the 'bord2.css' and constantly change it back and forward. Somewhere in the if-else it crashes and doesn't show the original CSS file.

```
$('#change-look').click(function (){
   if($('link[href]' == "style/bord.css")) {
      $('link[href="style/bord.css"]').attr('href','style/bord2.css');
   } else {
      $('link[href="style/bord2.css"]').attr('href','style/bord.css');
   }
});
```

Thanks for the help!

Greetings
Pj

Comment: I think you answered your own question...

Comment: @JeffUK my code seems promising, but it doesn't execute well. Like I said, button click works for the first change to the CSS. But clicking again does nothing :(

Answer (score 0):

May i suggest. Instead of having two different .css files, create two different css classes like so:

CSS:

```
.boardA{
 }
 .boardB{
 }
```

And considering your html looks something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class='boardA' id="chessBoard"></div>
```

Then in you click event, instead of changing the .css files, switch the classes instead.

JS

```
   $('#change-look').click(function (){
      var chessBoard = $("#chessBoard");
      if(chessBoard.hasClass('boardA')){
            chessBoard.removeClass('boardA');
            chessBoard.addClass('boardB');
      }
      else{
            chessBoard.removeClass('boardB');
            chessBoard.addClass('boardA');
      }
   });
```

I know it's not a direct answer to your question, nor i know if swapping complete .css files is a good practice or not, but i've used this approach dozens of times without any issues.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help man! Really appreciate it, but I have to work with 2 different CSS files, part of the task. It has to be done like that.

Comment: :( Too bad. I'll keep an eye to the post. I'm also interested in how this can be done reliably.